# ZF2 - Job queue to create a PDF file using SlmQueueBeanstalkd and DOMPDFModule

Tags: php, zend-framework2, pdf-generation, dompdf, job-queue

I'm trying to run a job queue to create a PDF file using `SlmQueueBeanstalkd` and `DOMPDFModule` in ZF".

Here's what I'm doing in my controller:

```
public function reporteAction()
{

    $job = new TareaReporte();
    $queueManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('SlmQueue\Queue\QueuePluginManager');
    $queue = $queueManager->get('myQueue');
    $queue->push($job);
    
    ...

}
```

This is the job:

```
namespace Application\Job;

use SlmQueue\Job\AbstractJob;
use SlmQueue\Queue\QueueAwareInterface;
use SlmQueue\Queue\QueueInterface;
use DOMPDFModule\View\Model\PdfModel;

class TareaReporte extends AbstractJob implements QueueAwareInterface
{

    protected $queue;

    public function getQueue()
    {
        return $this->queue;
    }

    public function setQueue(QueueInterface $queue)
    {
        $this->queue = $queue;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $sm = $this->getQueue()->getJobPluginManager()->getServiceLocator();
        $empresaTable = $sm->get('Application\Model\EmpresaTable');
        $registros = $empresaTable->listadoCompleto();
        $model = new PdfModel(array('registros' => $registros));
        $model->setOption('paperSize', 'letter');
        $model->setOption('paperOrientation', 'portrait');
        $model->setTemplate('empresa/reporte-pdf');

        $output = $sm->get('viewPdfrenderer')->render($model);

        $filename = "/path/to/pdf/file.pdf";
        file_put_contents($filename, $output);
    }
}
```

The first time you run it, the file is created and the work is successful, however, if you run a second time, the task is buried and the file is not created.

It seems that stays in an endless cycle when trying to render the model a second time.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue and it turned out it was because of the way ZendPdf\PdfDocument reuses it's object factory. Are you using ZendPdf\PdfDocument?

You might need to correctly close factory.

```
class MyDocument extends PdfDocument
{
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->_objFactory->close();
    }
}
```

Try to add this or something similar to the PdfDocument class...

update : it seem you are not using PdfDocument, however I suspect this is the issue is the same. Are you able to regenerate a second PDF in a normal http request? It is your job to make sure the environment is equal on each run.
If you are unable to overcome this problem a short-term quick solution would be to set max_runs configuration for SlmQueue to 1. That way the worker is stopped after each job and this reset to a vanilla state...

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond. Your reply has been helpful.

I have not been able to locate what is causing the problem. For now, I opted for the quick fix set max_runs SlmQueue to 1. Stopping the worker after each job creates pdf document correctly.